# Why doesn't Shift + R work in Blender 2.81?

Tags: modeling

The repeat last works on Blender 2.81 while printing command *repeat last* works. But it won't repeat while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Is it a bug?

Comment: It depends on what operation you did last, could you explain your situation or give an example, as your question does not give much to base an answer on.

Comment: I duplicate an object and grab it along the x axis.

Comment: It works on blender2.80. After I update it to 2.81, only the command works.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, both 2.81 and a recent version of the master branch both work fine.

Comment: pressing "shift+d" to get a copy and right away pressing "x" essentially is the same as first making a copy and then moving the copy like with "g" and then "x", so repeating the last operation will do only the moving part.

Answer (score 1):

Say you duplicate and edit in the box on the left bottom corner, pressing it at that moment will repeat the action. Doing a random action after that cancels your intent.